# Why validation works wrong?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

This is validation rule:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|array',
            'email.*' => 'required|email'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }
```

This data that with header: `application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json` I send using client:

```
[{"email":"oli35@mail.ru"},{"email":"zakaji-buket@mail.ru"}]
```

Also I tried:

```
{"emails":["oliss@mail.ru"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to send it as array:

```
[{"email":["oli35@mail.ru","zakaji-buket@mail.ru"]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try below.

```
public function __construct() {
    Validator::extend("emails", function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
        foreach ($value as $email) {
            $data = [
                'email' => $email
            ];
            $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

In your function

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|emails'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }
```

And send data like

```
{"email":["oli35@mail.ru","zakaji-buket@mail.ru"]}
```

I'm not tested it but this will helps you.